# Create associative array in APEX to be send to API

Tags: apex

I want so send json data to API using APEX, what i want to do is create a json from associative array. how can I do it in apex?
how can i make associative array? for example
record['arrayKey1'] = 'good';
record['arrayKey2'] = '45';

then convert it to JSON, (this what i did):
String requestBody = JSON.serialize(new RequestWrapper(myID, mobNumber,'' ,message,UserInfo.getUserEmail() ));

then use it in HttpRequest.

I still not able to make associative array, how do i make it in APEX?

Comment: The basics of Apex data types are introduced in [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro) on Trailhead, including a brief description of Maps. They are covered more fully in the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `Map` object.

```
Map<String,String> dataMap = new Map<String,String>{
  'arrayKey1' => 'good',
  'arrayKey2' => '45'
};

String requestBody = JSON.serialize(dataMap);
```

You can also make the `Map` like this:

```
Map<String,String> dataMap = new Map<String,String>();
dataMap.put('arrayKey1','good');
dataMap.put('arrayKey2','45');
```